# Eclipse WindowBuilder HeapSize

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

Yesterday was working with my project, then I started getting that error and I cant get to the "Designer" option on window Builder
I get that error

```
Designer [1.9.1.201710100405.201805281523]: Java heap space
Java heap space
```

I readed that I have to low memory asigned so I assigned to it more on eclipse.ini but the problem still there.
Heres my eclipse.ini

```
    -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\NafigaJochishZnat\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
E:/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms2048m
-Xmx4096m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Also the code that I try to acces to design.

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import org.json.*;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.ScrollPane;

public class maine extends JFrame {


    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table_8;
    private JTable table_9;
    private JTable table;
    private JTable table_1;
    private JTable table_2;
    private JTable table_3;
    private JTable table_4;
    private JTable table_5;
    private JTable table_6;
    private JTable table_7;
    private JTable table_10;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    maine frame = new maine();
                    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
                    frame.setUndecorated(true);
                    frame.setVisible(true);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public maine() throws IOException {


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 1024, 800);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnDatos = new JMenu("Datos");
        menuBar.add(mnDatos);

        JMenu mnAadir = new JMenu("A\u00F1adir");
        mnDatos.add(mnAadir);

        JMenuItem mntmAlbaran = new JMenuItem("Albaran");
        mnAadir.add(mntmAlbaran);

        JMenuItem mntmCliente = new JMenuItem("Cliente");
        mnAadir.add(mntmCliente);

        JMenuItem mntmExistencia = new JMenuItem("Existencia");
        mnAadir.add(mntmExistencia);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Empleado");
        mnAadir.add(mntmNewMenuItem);

        JMenuItem mntmPedidoDeCliente = new JMenuItem("Pedido de Cliente");
        mnAadir.add(mntmPedidoDeCliente);

        JMenuItem mntmPedidoAProveedor = new JMenuItem("Pedido a Proveedor");
        mnAadir.add(mntmPedidoAProveedor);

        JMenuItem mntmProducto = new JMenuItem("Producto");
        mnAadir.add(mntmProducto);

        JMenu mnEliminar = new JMenu("Eliminar");
        mnDatos.add(mnEliminar);

        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Albaran");
        mnEliminar.add(menuItem);

        JMenuItem menuItem_1 = new JMenuItem("Cliente");
        mnEliminar.add(menuItem_1);

        JMenuItem menuItem_2 = new JMenuItem("Existencia");
        mnEliminar.add(menuItem_2);

        JMenuItem menuItem_3 = new JMenuItem("Empleado");
        mnEliminar.add(menuItem_3);

        JMenuItem menuItem_4 = new JMenuItem("Pedido de Cliente");
        mnEliminar.add(menuItem_4);

        JMenuItem menuItem_5 = new JMenuItem("Pedido a Proveedor");
        mnEliminar.add(menuItem_5);

        JMenuItem menuItem_6 = new JMenuItem("Producto");
        mnEliminar.add(menuItem_6);

        JMenu mnModificar = new JMenu("Modificar");
        mnDatos.add(mnModificar);

        JMenuItem menuItem_7 = new JMenuItem("Albaran");
        mnModificar.add(menuItem_7);

        JMenuItem menuItem_8 = new JMenuItem("Cliente");
        mnModificar.add(menuItem_8);

        JMenuItem menuItem_9 = new JMenuItem("Existencia");
        mnModificar.add(menuItem_9);

        JMenuItem menuItem_10 = new JMenuItem("Empleado");
        mnModificar.add(menuItem_10);

        JMenuItem menuItem_11 = new JMenuItem("Pedido de Cliente");
        mnModificar.add(menuItem_11);

        JMenuItem menuItem_12 = new JMenuItem("Pedido a Proveedor");
        mnModificar.add(menuItem_12);

        JMenuItem menuItem_13 = new JMenuItem("Producto");
        mnModificar.add(menuItem_13);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        routes router = new routes();
        String ruta = router.getruta();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(10, 29, 988, 721);
        contentPane.add(tabbedPane);

        JScrollPane Albaran = new JScrollPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Albaranes", null, Albaran, null);

        table_1 = new JTable();

        table_1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(138);
        table_1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(161);
        table_1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(213);
        Albaran.setViewportView(table_1);

        JScrollPane Clientes = new JScrollPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Clientes", null, Clientes, null);

        table_2 = new JTable();

        table_2.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(95);
        table_2.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(151);
        table_2.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(131);
        table_2.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(187);
        table_2.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(118);
        table_2.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(156);
        Clientes.setViewportView(table_2);

        JScrollPane Empleados = new JScrollPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Empleados", null, Empleados, null);

        table_3 = new JTable();

        table_3.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(133);
        table_3.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(144);
        Empleados.setViewportView(table_3);

        JScrollPane Existencias = new JScrollPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Existencias", null, Existencias, null);

        table_4 = new JTable();

        table_4.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(170);
        table_4.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(157);
        Existencias.setViewportView(table_4);

        JScrollPane pedcli = new JScrollPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Pedidos de los Clientes", null, pedcli, null);

        table_5 = new JTable();

        table_5.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(122);
        table_5.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(123);
        table_5.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(100);
        table_5.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(225);
        pedcli.setViewportView(table_5);

        JScrollPane PedidosProv = new JScrollPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Pedidos a proveedores", null, PedidosProv, null);

        table_6 = new JTable();

        table_6.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(124);
        table_6.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(116);
        table_6.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(133);
        table_6.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(126);
        table_6.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(156);
        PedidosProv.setViewportView(table_6);

        JScrollPane Productos = new JScrollPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Productos", null, Productos, null);

        table = new JTable();

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(165);
        Productos.setViewportView(table);

        JScrollPane Proveedores = new JScrollPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Proveedores", null, Proveedores, null);

        table_7 = new JTable();

        table_7.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(127);
        table_7.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(109);
        table_7.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(141);
        Proveedores.setViewportView(table_7);

    }
}
```

Somebody got any idea why this happens also if I increase the memory assigned to exlipse x4 times?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Mark I cant remove anycode because the problem seems with full code. Also its only this file which does the problem. Any other class didn't give the problem. Also its a Eclipse/WindowBuilder memory problem and I didn't fix it with memory increasing. Looks like I have to much things in the code but I need to know what to do solve the memory problem without remove anycode.

Comment: Ten tables are definitiely NOT too many things. You use classes that I don't have access to, which is not a problem because I think the mistake is in them, but because it means I can't reproduce your problem to test it myself. So even if I were inclined to ignore your horrible naming conventions, I still couldn't help you. If the problem isn't in the other classes, remove the lines that use them. It should mean you still get the problem but then I can actually test it myself.

Comment: also: i don't mean remove them in your original code, just create an example that doesn't have those lines and still produces the problem in addition to your original code.

Comment: Sorry @Mark I was wrong. Deleted every reference to another class and my problem still here. Idk what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Well if your problem is still there, that's what we wanted, right? Just post the new code :D

Comment: Post edited, updated to the version without other class code.

Comment: Okay there's  still some class named routes. Also, if you remove the entire menubar and all but one table, do you still have the same problem?

Comment: @Mark Looks like when I remove only 1 table (Doesn't matters which) it works without the class "parse" but when I put some code in it brokes again. But when I use eclipse in Ubuntu works :/ Looks like my Windows Eclipse has some problems.

Answer (score 0):

At the end the only thing that worked was to reinstall the JDK and Eclipe. Looks like windows gone mad with them.